# What element/view is being used here?

Tags: android, view

[image]

I saw this app and it works great but I want to know that which view is used here for the sliders i.e. time length, no of questions. And the base of the sliders are image or what?
Also the settings which is highlighted, is it also an image??

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps they used this one? Have a look at this github project
https://github.com/pellucide/Android-Switch-Demo-pre-4.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever you like

```
1) you can make custom switch view

2) you can make images and than apply to LinearLayout or relative layout and swap view as per you click on that view.
```